# Count specific field in dataframe groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm new to Python and trying to get my head around how to manipulate Pandas dataframes. I'm using the winemag-data-130k-v2.csv dataset. 
The fields of interest are 'country','province','winery'variety'.

The first thing I'd like to do is determine the number of wineries per province.
I can get as far as 
`reviews_df.groupby(['country','province']).size()`

But this gives me the number of rows. (So, 3 if a winery produces 3 varieties).
But I want something like a `count(distinct winery)` in SQL.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [nunique()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
reviews_df.groupby(['country','province']).nunique()
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.
This will give unique counts for all columns. If you just want winery limit the columns shown.
`reviews_df.groupby(['country','province'])['winery'].nunique()`